# Wordpress 404 redirects from /site.webmanifest

Tags: wordpress, redirect, web-manifest

I had a client ask this question and have no idea how to answer or if it's indeed a concern. They went into Tools/Redirection/404s from the wp-admin bar and found that multiple times a minute there are redirect requests from /site.webmanifest. The vast majority of the IPs are within 50 miles of the client. This seems benign but I don't understand what's happening and would like to know more. Thanks!